# Get Azure Security Center alerts via python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python, securitycenter

I want to list azure security center alerts using the python SDK.

I found this package:
https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-security/

It must be included in the microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/python/azure/?view=azure-python
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python

but I can not find any reference or example.

Does anyone know where I can find this information?

Best regards.

Comment: I have updated my code. If it's helpful, could you please help mark it as answer following this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can just give a rough reference.

After install the package [azure-mgmt-security](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-security/), you should use `List` method in the package, source code is [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/security/azure-mgmt-security/azure/mgmt/security/operations/alerts_operations.py#L40).

Here is the the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/python-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-python#mgmt-auth-token) on how to authentication.
Here is [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal) on how to get tenantId / client_id / key.

Here is my code:

```
from azure.mgmt.security import SecurityCenter
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

subscription_id = "xxxx"

# Tenant ID for your Azure subscription
TENANT_ID = '<Your tenant ID>'

# Your service principal App ID
CLIENT = '<Your service principal ID>'

# Your service principal password
KEY = '<Your service principal password>'

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = CLIENT,
    secret = KEY,
    tenant = TENANT_ID
)

client = SecurityCenter(credentials=credentials,subscription_id=subscription_id,asc_location="centralus")
client.alerts.list()
```

Also, you can use [List Alerts api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securitycenter/alerts/list) with a http request in python.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, February 2021, Microsoft again changed the way credentials are instantiated. Here is the current one:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

# Acquire a credential object for the app identity. When running in the cloud,
# DefaultAzureCredential uses the app's managed identity (MSI) or user-assigned service principal.
# When run locally, DefaultAzureCredential relies on environment variables named
# AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, and AZURE_TENANT_ID.

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
```

And it also changed the SecurityCenter signature, the `credentials` parameter was renamed to `credential` without the "s".

Full documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-authenticate?view=azure-python&tabs=cmd#mgmt-auth-token).