# How do I get ASC (Azure Security Center) location using Azure SDK

Tags: azure, go

I am trying to achieve what this REST API does but using Go SDK for Azure.

[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Security/locations?api-version=2015-06-01-preview](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/providers/Microsoft.Security/locations?api-version=2015-06-01-preview)

The idea is to get the ASC (Azure Security Center) location based on subscription.
The nearest that I could find is security.NewLocationsClient, but this needs a location as input. Using REST API is straightforward, but looking for function exposed in SDK to achieve the same.

Comment: Found similar issue faced in Azure SDK for python. And one of the solution suggested and accepted is to use REST API to find the location and then use the SDK for further work. I am already aware of this possibility, so will progress with that approach as it seems  that this is common SDK issue across languages.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65619297/is-it-possible-to-get-the-asc-location-from-the-azure-python-sdk